# MySQL - Delete value in the row, instead of deleting the row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete the searched value (not row) if a row contains the searched value. For example, if I want to remove banana, it should only remove banana from the rows which contain banana.

Tried this,

```
DELETE FROM users where eat like '%banana%'
```

However, it removes the rows. So how can I remove only search value from the rows ?

Comment: You need an update statement.

Comment: do you need empty the column of rows which have the value you search?

Comment: No, just want to remove the searched value from the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
UPDATE users SET eat = REPLACE(eat, 'banana', '') where eat like '%banana%';
```

This would replace only `banana` from `eat` column where it is present.

**Update**

Loop through the data and replace those values. This might help -

```
$check_val = 'banana';

//select those rows first
"select id, eat from users where eat like '%" . $check_val . "%'"

foreach($data as $v) {

    $temp= explode(',', $v['eat']);
    $temp= array_map(function($t) use($check_val) {
        return (strpos($t, $check_val) !== false) ? null : $t;
    }, $temp);
    $temp = array_filter($temp);
    $v['eat']= implode(',', $temp);

    "update users set eat= '" . $v['eat'] . "' where eat like '%" . $check_val . "%'"
}
```

Comment: does it replace for example, newbanana too ?

Comment: No, It would replace only `banana`. For that you have to do some manipulations. How are you storing those values?

Comment: Ok, just asked for curiosity. Values are stored as banana,apple,mushroom

Comment: So each time a record found, it runs a mysql command right ? What if there are 1000 rows which contain banana ?

Comment: Btw, the update script is for repeated banana records in the row, or what is the difference with the first one ?

Comment: For that case you can write a `mysql function` which would return the replaced value.

Comment: The first 1 wouldn't replace `newbanana` or `banana,`.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users SET eat = null where eat like '%banana%';
```

OR

```
UPDATE users SET eat = '' where eat like '%banana%';
```

Comment: Should only use #1 if the field allows nulls, just thought I might add that :P

Comment: It just emptying the rows I guess, I only want to remove the searched value.

Comment: Yes you are correct. That why I mentioned Or with another query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
update users set eat='' where eat like '%banana%'
```

Comment: This is just emptying the `eat` column.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Update users  
 set eat =  'your value' 
 where eat like '%banana%' ;
```