# MySQL - replace the searched value in the rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace(remove) the searched name on the rows which includes the name. For example, if I remove the John name from the rows,

It could be done using;

```
UPDATE users SET friends = REPLACE(friends, 'john', '') where friends like '%john%';
```

However; the problem is, values are stored like below in the rows;

```
,John|1428352438,,Megan|1462548732,,Fox|1426825014,,Ramy|1428352438,
```

The numbers are representing the date they have been added. So if I want to remove `,John|1428352438,` which method should I use to remove it ? (the date numbers changes on every record)

Comment: This can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264796/mysql-delete-value-in-the-row-instead-of-deleting-the-row/35264862#35264862

Comment: So, you want the column to be blank space?

Comment: You must use two columns: one for name and onother one for date

Comment: Maybe you should use `ilike`

Comment: @Sougata How, it has also numbers here...

Comment: @sagi I just want to delete the searched value with the numbers.

Comment: Try that code after **Update**.